# How to remove the last dot from a string in bash?

Tags: sed

I have a string as below:

```
domain="abc-xyz.com."
```

I need to remove the `.` at the last so it would look like `abc-xyz.com`

I tried this and it doesn't work as it is expecting a file

```
sed 's/\.$//' $domain
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Answering OP's issue's fix:*** Since you are reading input from a variable, then that's not the correct way to pass value from variable to `sed` what you are using shown in your question(you must be getting `No such file or directory` error while executing your code).

Try using:

```
echo "$domain" | sed 's/\.$//'
```

OR use:

```
sed 's/\.$//' <<<"$domain"
```

***Ideal way to deal is could be:*** Try following if you are ok to use parameter expansion as shown by @anubhava sir in comments.

```
var="${domain%.}"
```

Comment: How can I get the final output to another variable?

Comment: @JananathJayarathna, please don't keep adding your questions/requirements to your already asked questions that is NOT encouraged on SO. You could use `var=$(echo "$domain" | sed 's/\.$//')` to do so, but please try to keep 1 question at a time in post, thank you.

Comment: Or `var="${domain%.}"`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\./\1/' file
```

Use greed to locate the last period and replace it by what came before it.